# function that return a array of no predefined size

Tags: javascript, webassembly

in my C code i have a function that generate a array with a size unknown before calling that function , for example, that array will contain all pixels with red > 128.

The C program is simple, and no problem. I use malloc and realloc.

Now, in javascript, after the ccall, i want get the result (an array) in a Uint8ClampedArray.

In all tutorials i've readen, the array that is return from the C side is with a given length, say L byte.
So we use :

```
  pointer = Module._malloc(L)
  Module.HEAPU8.set(my_Uint8ClampedArray, pointerResult);
```

BUT, in my code, the length of the resulting array is not known until the end of the C function :

```
int imageGrayscale(unsigned char *data) {

    int l = some_function(...)
    data = malloc( l * sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (int i = 0; i < l ; i++) { 
         data[i]=  //some_value//; }

    return l; 
   // return the size of *data in case of...
   // but the value that matter is *data.
}
```

Here is the Javascript code where i do not manage retrieve *data :

```
var wa_imageGrayscale =module.cwrap('imageGrayscale',['number'],['number']);
var arrayOut = Module._malloc(// how_get_the_size_before_calling //);
var size_of_arrayOut = wa_imageGrayscale(arrayOut);
var  = new Uint8ClampedArray(size_of_arrayOut);
...???
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, the function `imageGrayscale()` has a parameter with a pointer of char then you use `malloc()` with it. Really? You probably want a double pointer to char.

Comment: @BumsikKim not a pointer of string but o pointer of unsigned bytes. I use malloc inside the function because i do not know how many bytes before calling that function.